# Validate yyyy-mm input in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a site where we collect dates for employment history, in this case, we don't want to collect a day, just year and month, I am using a jquery datepicker, example date: 2020-10 (yyyy-mm).

I have been trying to find a validation rule for Laravel without success, I am assuming this should be a custom validator, but I have no clue where to start.

Comment: Have you tried this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-date-format ? `date_format:Y-m`

Answer (score 3):

#### `date_format:format`

> The field under validation must match the given format. You should use either `date` or `date_format` when validating a field, not both. This validation rule supports all formats supported by PHP's [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

---

```php
$validator = Validator::make(
    ['date' => '2020-10'], 
    ['date' => 'date_format:Y-m']
);

$validator->passes(); // TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am currently testing your rule. My field is only required if another field is selected, please see my rule: 'busy_studying_start_date' => 'required_if:education_status,busy_studying|date_format:Y-m'. How can I make this new rule conditional?

Comment: Adding nullable worked for me. 'busy_studying_start_date' => 'required_if:education_status,busy_studying|nullable|date_format:Y-m

Answer (score 1):

You can validate your date using regex

```
$request->validate([
    'date' => 'bail|required|regex:/([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2]))/',
]);
```